# unexpected exception encontered during query on railo

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, railo

I am trying to import large files of size more than 500 mb to some gbs in mean while getting this error `unexpected exception encontered during query` though I am using `<cfsettting requesttimeout = 1000000 >`. when i have changed in Railo web admin it works but I want to do it by using `cfsetting tag`. can anyone help me what i have to do for using cffsetting tag inside the page ? Thanks.

I am using

MySQL 5.5.35
Railo 4.2.0 on ubuntu 12.04.

requestimeout.log

```
"Severity","ThreadID","Date","Time","Application","Message"
"ERROR","Thread-3","03/06/2014","04:05:24","controler","stop thread (3) because run into a timeout .;java.lang.Throwable;java.lang.Throwable
    at railo.runtime.tag.Http4._doEndTag(Http4.java:611)
    at railo.runtime.tag.Http4.doEndTag(Http4.java:596)
    at admin.resources.text_cfm$cf.call(/railo-context-compiled/admin/resources/text.cfm:48)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:885)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:793)
    at admin.web_cfm$cf.call(/railo-context-compiled/admin/web.cfm:124)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:885)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:837)
    at railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:208)
    at railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener.onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:86)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2182)
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2149)
    at railo.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:332)
    at railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
"
```

Comment: Can you post any errors you see in Railo's requesttimeout.log?

Comment: @CoryFail - i have edited my question with requestimeout.log error.

Comment: I could be wrong. Can you try `cfset = URL.requestTimeout = 100000`?

Comment: yeah tried it still getting the same error :(

Comment: Try enabling your `AllowURLRequestTimeout` if you haven't already.

Comment: Tried it still no difference.

Comment: The `cfsetting requesttimeout` is expecting seconds, not milliseconds. So your value of `1000000` is like 11.5 days. I don't think that is going to work. Set it to something more reasonable. Where have you placed this tag in your code?

Comment: i was thinking it is in miliseconds, I have placed it at first line in a page.

Comment: @Sulemankhan - Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having trouble changing the request timeout on Railo 4.2.1. Even updating it in the server and web admins isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is quoted in Google Railo group by (Michael Offner-Streit,CTO,Railo Technologies GmbH)
we can not begin with the execution of cfml files before we have recieved the request header.
because the railo servlet is not invoked before.
you can set also timeouts on the servlet engines (resin,tomcat ...) most of them support this.

there is also a other way to set per page requesttimeout. simply add the following to the url of the call like index.cfm?RequestTimeout=100
for security reasion this feature is not enabled by default, you have to enabe it as follows,
got to the railo admin to settings/application (/railo-context/admin/web.cfm?action=server.application), there you find "Request timeout in URL" enable this.

but also this takes only effect when railo is invoked.

/micha

btw: index.cfm?RequestTimeout=100 works also on ACF5,ACF7,ACF8,ACF9 but not on ACF6, they have also removed this for security reasion in ACF6 but silently added again in version 7.

**Note:** I think that should explain your problem. You can do it by adding it in url and modifying the settings (enabeling request time out) in railo web admin, it will also ensure that setting is not applicable on all the pages if done from railo admin.